# power shell command to find all vm instance series that support the premium disk

Tags: azure, powershell

is there any PowerShell script that project.
"List all Virtual instance series that support premium disk along with region vise."

if available anyone, could you share it please.

it's getting list of azure regions but I couldn't find the series.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.